# Comando para calcular los factores primos de un número

Tags: r

En lenguaje R, ¿existe un comando para calcular los factores primos de un número?

Answer (score 1):

No, al menos con **R base**, este tipo de calculo no es común en el ámbito de las estadísticas de ahí que no exista una función base para ello. Hay varias opciones.

#### 1. Construir tu propia rutina

Voy a adaptar algo el código de [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36402001/6836377) excelente respuesta:

```
my_primeFactors <- function(num) {

    current <- num
    ret.vals <- vector()
    x <- 2
    while (x <= num - 1){
        while (current %% x == 0) {
            current <- current / x
            ret.vals <- c(ret.vals, x)
        }
        x <- x + 1
    }
    if (is.logical(ret.vals)) return(num) else return(ret.vals)
}
```

Ejemplo:

```
> my_primeFactors(12)
[1] 2 2 3
```

La idea es la forma más habitual de factorizar primos (hay algoritmos más avanzados y óptimos), básicamente vamos iterando `x` desde el primo 2 (el 1 es divisor de cualquier número) y mientras sea divisor de `current` vamos incorporando este factor a la lista, y dividiendo `current` por dicho factor y de vuelta a probar. Cuando `x` deja de ser divisor intentamos con los siguientes `x` hasta que encontremos el próximo primo divisor, y así hasta completar la lista. Sin duda esta será la opción menos performante, como mejora podríamos eventualmente implementarla en `C++` mediante `Rcpp`.

#### 2. Usar [`primeFactors()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/numbers/versions/0.6-6/topics/primeFactors) de `library("numbers")`

[`numbers`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/numbers/index.html) "Number-Theoretic Functions" es un paquete de **R** que se instala de la forma habitual `install.packages("numbers")`, este paquete ofrece muchas funciones clásicas de la teoría matemática, la que nos interesa particularmente es [`primeFactors()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/numbers/versions/0.6-6/topics/primeFactors)

```
> primeFactors(n)
[1] 2 2 3
```

#### 3. Usar [`factorize()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gmp/versions/0.5-13/topics/factorization) de `library("gmp")`

[`gmp`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmp/index.html) "Multiple Precision Arithmetic (big integers and rationals, prime number tests, matrix computation), "arithmetic without limitations" using the C library GMP (GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic)." es otro paquete del cual usaremos [`factorize()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gmp/versions/0.5-13/topics/factorization). Este paquete permite manejar números muchos más grandes de los que puede `numbers`.

```
> as.numeric(factorize(12))
[1] 2 2 3
```

Si vemos estas opciones en función de la performance:

```
> n <- 15745231
> # Rutina ad-hoc
> system.time({my_primeFactors(n)})
   user  system elapsed 
  9.980   0.000  10.031 
> # Paquete "numbers"
> system.time({primeFactors(n)})
   user  system elapsed 
  0.004   0.000   0.001 
> # Paquete "gmp"
> system.time({as.numeric(factorize(n))})
   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       0
```

Claramente [`gmp`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmp/index.html) es la opción ganadora.

Answer (score 0):

**No existe un comando** como tal, tienes que diseñar o buscar un algoritmo para calcular esa información y luego implementarlo usando el lenguaje R en este caso.

Comment: De acuerdo, muchas gracias. Si que he visto que existe, factorize(número),  que devuelve los factores primos pero no de la forma que necesito.

Answer (score 0):

Tu pregunta fue planteada en la versión de [SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34043279/5587982). Esta función podría serte útil para lo que buscas:

```
library(gmp)
getPrimeFactors = function(n){
    primeList=c()
    if(isprime(n)){
        primeList <- append(primeList, n)
        return (primeList)
    }
    currentPrime <- 2
    while(TRUE){
        # Check if input is divisible by the current primeList
        if(n %% currentPrime == 0){
            cat(sprintf("the number %f is divisible by %f\n", n, currentPrime))
            n = n%/%currentPrime
            cat(sprintf("current prime :%f\n", currentPrime))
            primeList = append(primeList,currentPrime)
            currentPrime = 2
            if(isprime(n)){
                primeList <- append(primeList, n)
                return (primeList)
            }
        }
        else{
            #cat(sprintf("the number %f is NOT divisible by %f\n", n, currentPrime))
            #cat(sprintf("current prime before is: %f\n", currentPrime))
            print(c("current prime before:", currentPrime))
            currentPrime = as.numeric(nextprime(currentPrime))
            #cat(sprintf("current prime after is: %f\n", currentPrime))
            print(c("current prime after:", currentPrime))
        }
    }
}
```

---

Puedes ver también [esta otra pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19767408/5587982).